# Two Cart Price Rules are applying incorrect discounts

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.4.6

I am experiencing an issue where two **Cart Price Rules** are returning incorrect discounts.

- Rule 1 apply 20% discount
- Rule 2 apply 30% discount

The total **50%** discount should be applied. For example, if the Subtotal is **$1700**, the discount amount should be **$850**. But a **$748** discount is applied.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This calculation is perfectly correct. If you first subtract 20% from 1700, 1360 remains. Then rule 2 where 30% is subtracted from 1360: 408.
1360 - 408 = 952 which is 748.

If you want to give 50% discount you should change your second percentage to 37,5%.